# Is there a way to keep track of javascript hits?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, html

I am populating a table based on a javascript function.  I want to limit the data entered to 2, afterwhich I hide the table.  Is there a way to track how many hits the javascript code gets hit?

```
function addNewRow() {
    $('#displayInjuryTable tr:last').after('<tr><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="name"></td><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="address"></td></tr>');
    var $tr = $('#displayInjuryTable tr:last');
    var propertyCondition = $('#txtInjuryAddress').val();


    $tr.find('.name').text($('#txtInjuryName').val());
    if (propertyCondition != "") {
        $tr.find('.address').text($('#txtInjuryAddress').val() + ', ' + $('#txtInjuryCity').val() + ' ' + $('#txtInjuryState').val() + ' ' + $('#txtInjuryZip').val());
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var someCounter = 0

function addNewRow() {
  if(someCounter>1) {
    return
  }   
  someCounter++
 ...your code...
}
```

Comment: you need to hide the table before the "return" per OP specification.

Answer (score 0):

```
var addNewRow = (function(){
    var count = 0;
    return function(){
        if (++count === 2) {
            //hide feature 
            return;
        }
        ... // your code here
    }
})();
```